# Как разместить в UISlider изображение на задний фон во всю длину

Tags: objective-c, ios

Привет всем! Я создаю кастомизированный UISlider, на заднем фоне у меня должно находиться изображение, которое должно открываться по мере перемещения ползунка в UISlider, однако, MinimumTrackImage размещается странным образом, оно уживается по ширине и по мере передвижения слайдера расширяется на длину слайдера. Я бы хотел достичь эффекта постепенного открытия, как это можно сделать, заранее спасибо! С MaximumTrackImage, все нормально, работает как и задумывалось.

minImage = [minImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
maxImage = [maxImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];

```
UIImage *thumbImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"picker.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[self.view addSubview:navigationSlider];
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать заменить строку:

```
minImage = [minImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
```

на эту:

```
minImage = [minImage resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero
                                    resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeTile];
```

Будет другой эффект. Возможно он больше подойдет.